# CAN/J1939 Bus Protocol - Difference between Command and Request

Tags: can

In a CAN Bus, there are no Master/Slave configurations.

However, I've seen multiple uses of both command signals as well as request signals.
Although they seem to be interchangeable, wouldn't "request" make more sense here?

You can't exactly command another module to do something as all modules are on the same level and the priority is handled within the messaging, correct?

Comment: It would help if you gave a specific example of a J1939 message or provision you're asking about. (I sympathize: I also found the J1939 spec to be intolerably convoluted, but it's not really clear what you're asking.) Welcome to the site!

Comment: @TypeIA Thanks! Sure thing - for example, there's PGN 61715 SPN 8571 which is DC/DC 1 Loadshed Request. On the other hand, we have PGN 61654 SPN 8336 which is a DC/AC Accessory Inverter 1 Operational Command. My question is about the wording I guess; wouldn't a "request" make more sense than a "command" in this case for SPN 8336?

Comment: Are you sure "request" and "command" here are used in some J1939 structural sense? Is it not that the first PGN encodes a parameter related to _a loadshed request_ and the second PGN encodes a parameter related to _an operational command_? Neither of these are related to a **J1939 request** (PGN 59904).

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying -  when creating proprietary messages/signals then where you are "commanding/requesting" info - is there a right answer? So when you request the status of the park brake for example - would Park Brake Request or Park Brake Command make more sense?

Answer (score 3):

Do not confuse CAN (which is little more than a messaging facility) with J1939 which is higher level and works over CAN.

The command/request is more a philosophical one, *especially* on J1939. In particular request in J1939 lingo means exactly one thing i.e. using PGN 59904 to tell "somebody (or just you depending on the addressing) send this PGN I'm telling you since I need to know)

A command on the other hand like "turn on the wiper" is often more like "this is the value that I want on this SPN"; not always, there are cases where an SPN is declared as 'command parameter' like if I set it to  'whatever' crush the garbage in the compactor.

Comment: Thanks for the response - when creating proprietary messages/signals then where you are "commanding/requesting" info - is there a right answer? So when you request the status of the park brake for example - would Park Brake Request or Park Brake Command make more sense?